# ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow Ruby On Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, passenger

I can not save user data as there is a problem with the size of cookies (4KB)

I Centos server, Nginx, Passenger

```
actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:305:in `[]='
actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:64:in `set_cookie'
rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:335:in `commit_session'
rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:211:in `context'
rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.22) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__4594969678639542870__call__4298955712328050144__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.22) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.22) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.22) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.22) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.22) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.22) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.22) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.22) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:83:in `call'
railties (3.2.22) lib/rails/engine.rb:484:in `call'
railties (3.2.22) lib/rails/application.rb:231:in `call'
railties (3.2.22) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
passenger (5.0.26) src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:97:in `process_request'
passenger (5.0.26) src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:160:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
passenger (5.0.26) src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:113:in `main_loop'
passenger (5.0.26) src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:416:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
passenger (5.0.26) src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:113:in `block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'
```

Comment: Hello new user! I see you're encountering problems saving user data. Unfortunately, an error dump by itself isn't useful to experts trying to help you: you need to ask a specific question and provide more context. What were you trying to do? Why do you think your approach is failing? Is there something specific about the error you don't understand? What do you need to know to resolve the problem? Remember that Stack Overflow is a Q&A site: without a specific question, it's hard to help you with your problem. Ask a specific question, and experts are far more likely to help you. Good luck! :)

Comment: The problem with this error is that it doesn't tell you where in your code there is a problem to be fixed.  In my case, I did not try to write to a cookie.  The error references code we don't write/maintain (not sure why such are ever shown by default - just makes it harder to find the line referring to code we wrote).  Maybe this should be a bug-report?